# missing designs in a navigated page developed in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am very new in codeigniter and I am facing lots of problems while I develop my website with it. I am facing basic navigation problem. First of all I've to say where my files are situated.   My `css`,`js` and `image` file are situated at the root folder, that is where the `application` folder is situated. And my other files which contains html, php, js code are situated in `view` folder . My controller is like that:

```
<?php

 class Saffron extends CI_Controller

{
   function index()
      {
       $this->load->view('header');
       $this->load->view('index');
               $this->load->view('footer');


     }  
 function book_table()
 {

   $this->load->view('book_table');
 }

    }
?>
```

I am trying to navigate to my 'book_table.php' page  from my `home` page. Now see my `nevigation.php` page from where I am navigating my webpages (just showing the basic header part and anchor tags):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/slider.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/book.css">
  <!--<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
  family=Great+Vibes' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vpb_script.js"></script>
  <script src="js/pop.js"></script>

  <!--start popup window ref-->
  <link href="css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script src="js/jquery_002.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".image_show").colorbox({rel:'image_show', transition:"fade"});

    });
</script>
<!--end popup window ref-->

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){                   
        $('.slider')._TMS({
            show:0,
            pauseOnHover:true,
            prevBu:false,
            nextBu:false,
            playBu:false,
            duration:700,
            preset:'fade',
            pagination:true,
            pagNums:false,
            slideshow:8000,
            numStatus:false,
            banners:false,
            waitBannerAnimation:false,
            progressBar:false
        })      
    });
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
/*This will work for chrome */
    #vpb_general_button{
        padding:5px 2px 4px 2px;
    }

/*This will work for firefox*/
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #vpb_general_button{
        padding:5px 2px 6px 2px;
    }
}
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
   <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
     <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/
 internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
       <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/
 banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" 
 width="820" alt="You are using  an outdated browser. 
 For a faster, safer browsing    
 experience, 
 upgrade for free today." />
    </a>
  </div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div  class="nav_b">
    <nav>  
        <ul class="menu">
            <li ><a href="index.html">
                   Online Order
                 </a>
           </li>
            <li>
                 <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>
                   index.php/saffron/book_table">Book Table
                 </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                  Gallery
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <a href="#">
                    About Us
                 </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    Awards
                  </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">
                 Contact Us
               </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
     </nav>
 </div>
</body>
```

Now the problem is that I can navigate my `Book table` page but without the design. It's loading just like a basic html page, I can't understand why it's happening, because it doesn't find the css, js and images, isn't it? But my home page finds all and is fine, then why not the page(Book table) i am nevigating not finding the css,js and images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario make use of `base_url();`. In `application/config/config.php` specify `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yoursite.com';`

Then in view change the `link href` and `script src`

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php echo(base_url());?>css/reset.css">

 <script src="<?php echo(base_url());?>js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
```